# Third Parameter of .Slerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to move my the object that this script is attached to in a straight line from its position to a predetermined position in relation to how far a timer has charged. I want it to be halfway when the timer is halfway charged to the max, and at the point when it is fully charged etc. My issue is that it always reaches the point at a fraction of what the time should be, no matter how long the timer is supposed to charge up for. I tried finding the percent charged by dividing the current charge by the max charge, but it didn't work. Any solutions?

```
transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, pos, (chargeTimer/maxCharge));
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you should use [`Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html), not `Slerp` if you want a straight line. [`Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html), mostly useful for matters of direction rather than absolute position, will rotate around the point at (0,0,0) if possible.

Second, you need to remember what your starting position is, and use that as the first parameter:

```
Vector3 startPosition;
Vector3 pos;
float chargeTimer;
public float maxCharge;

...

    // where you start your timer
    chargeTimer = 0f;

    startPosition = transform.position;

...

    // where you update your position/timer
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, pos, (chargeTimer/maxCharge));
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. This is my first time using Lerp or Slerp, somebody far more experienced told me to use it for the function I had in mind.

Comment: That works better, only other thing might be to include a link to the Slerp doc page as well, but that reads better. I had to initially look at the Slerp page to even figure out what you meant by curve-around, which is why I said it wasn't *wrong* just *confusing.* Much better now. Cleaning up out dated comments.

Comment: @buddrfingrs Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)